# ViewPropertyAnimator set absolute position

Tags: android, android-animation, viewpropertyanimator

I have an ImageView and I want to make an animation like this (sorry for bad image, but I think it give a general idea of animation)
[image]

I used ViewPropertyAnimator:

```
img.animate()
       .translationX(50f)
       .translationY(500f)
       .setDuration(500)
       .start();
```

And I get this:
[image]

Why that?
Sorry for my bad English

Comment: In my opinion your X translation should be negative and not positive if you want to move your object backwards. Also you should convert your Float to DB to make sure you have the same effect on all kind of screens (Or create some dimensions in your resources).

Comment: @RóbertPolovitzer Yes, I thought the same. I didn't say that x and y values are coordinates of another view (I show it as number here for keep the example simple). How can I transform the x value to negative? I must get the screen width?

Comment: If I remember well, `translationX(-500f)` will be a relative movement from the current  x position. So you just have to decide how far you want to move your object.